# (Networking) XM6i emulating NetBSD 4.0.1 x68k

Tags: virtual-machine, 68000, netbsd

I have installed NetBSD 4.0.1 x68k on XM6i (http://www.ceres.dti.ne.jp/tsutsui/netbsd/x68k/NetBSD-x68k-on-XM6i.html) as a virtual machine emulating a 68030 platform. I have gotten everything to work except networking.

According to the documentation, you need to install a TAP-Win32 network adapter from OpenVPN installer, which I have. I have set the ipv4 settings of this adapter to IP address: 192.168.2.1 and Netmask: 255.255.255.0

In NetBSD, I have created a /etc/ifconfig.ne0 file to configure the ne0 network interface, which I assume represents the TAP-Win32 adapter. This file sets IP address to 192.168.2.17 and Netmask to 255.255.255.0

When i use "ping 192.168.2.1" on NetBSD I am unable to ping the host, the error message being: "host is down"

Does anyone know whats going wrong? If anyone could give me any advice I would be most grateful.

---

**Update:** Above problem has been solved .... but not quite.

If I have tinkered around with settings on host, now I can ping guest only if I run tcpdump -i ne0 on guest. Then after that I can also ping the host from the guest. I have tried restarting and trying without tcpdump but the changes didnt seem to stick, so i have to run tcpdump in order to setup the host only connection.

Is there any way I can do this without tcpdump and make the fix stick?

---

**Edit:** Here is the link to the new question with a more detailed explanation of the problem: [Host Only connection NetBSD to Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940075/host-only-connection-netbsd-to-windows)

Comment: can you ping localhost, i.e. what does `ping -n 127.0.0.1` do?

Comment: and what does `ifconfig -a` show?

Comment: Yes I can ping local host. And ifconfig -a shows ne0 interface and lo0 interface.

Comment: Hmmm.... I suppose you might try pinging the broadcast address for ne0 (192.168.2.255), and looking to see what `arp -an` says afterwards.  Maybe try tcpdump on ne0 and try pinging 192.168.2.255 on the emulator host to see if packets are arriving to NetBSD.  It doesn't sound like the problem is on the NetBSD side though.

Comment: Yes, I agree I think the issue maybe on Xm6i side but I couldnt find any tags for xm6i to add to this question. And arp -n localhost says no entry, same as arp -n 192.168.2.1 and arp -n 192.168.2.17. I also tried tcpdump and ping from host to guest on guest's broadcast but that didnt work either.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing of Xm6i, and so can't tell you more than the web page you've already referenced.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to run a complete networking emulation on a 68030 machine on the latest version of XM6i, you need to run tcpdump on boot. There is no way around it.