# Host Only connection NetBSD to Windows

Tags: networking, virtualization, netbsd

I have NetBSD-4.0.1-x68k installed as a guest virtual machine on Windows (using the XM6i 68030 emulator for windows 7). I am trying to setup a host only connection on the NetBSD guest. However, I can't ping the guest from the host unless I run:

```
tcpdump -i ne0 #executed on guest
ping 192.168.2.17 #executed on host
ping 192.168.2.1 #executed on guest
```

Right after I run these commands in that order I can continue to ping successfully ...but not forever, after a certain point I am unable to ping again from neither the host nor guest. Also, when I restart the system, I still can only do pings unless I do the above process beforehand, and again, not forever.

Is there anyway I can setup this host only connection without using tcpdump as a short term temporary handicap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out on the latest version of XM6i. In order to get a complete 68030 networking emulation you need to use tcpdump command on boot. So there is no way around this.